# PHP associative array replace location of the key

Tags: php, arrays

The following array is generated from the database and the key field "comp" is pushed into the array .
I want to generate the following output by traversing into the array and replacing the order .

Output of the array

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [fname] => Calvin
                [lname] => harris
                [age] => 22
                [comp] => IT
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [fname] => zayn
                [lname] => dusk
                [age] => 21
                [comp] => HR
            )

    )
```

the "comp" key should be listed after "lname"
So , if there is a array inbuilt function or an efficient code to obtain the output as shown below.

**The expected result should be**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [fname] => Calvin
            [lname] => harris
            [comp] => IT
            [age] => 22

        )   

)
```

Comment: Doesn't make sense. Why would you need something like that? Semantics? Why not setting the "order" when creating the array?

Comment: @OfirBaruch I want to do it to generate csv file ,the above is an example

Comment: @OfirBaruch  [comp] => IT is pushed using array_push remaining data is pulled from select query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an `array_key_up()` function for this.

```
foreach($arrays as &$array) {
    $array = array_key_up($array, 'comp');
}
```

---

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [fname] => Calvin
                [lname] => harris
                [comp] => IT
                [age] => 22
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [fname] => zayn
                [lname] => dusk
                [comp] => HR
                [age] => 21
            )

    )
```

---

**The needed function.**

```
function array_key_up($array, $key)
{
    $keys  = array_keys($array);
    $index = array_search($key, $keys, true);

    if ($index === false) {
        return $array;
    }
    $offset = max(0, $index - 1);

    return array_slice($array, 0, $offset, true)
        + array($key => $array[$key])
        + array_slice($array, $offset, null, true);
}
```

Comment: I believe that my solution is far more efficient, but nice code.

Comment: More efficient, I agree. In fact (cc @Sam) it would be better to construct the array in the desired order from the beginning; i.e., not need to slice and dice it after the array has already been established.

Answer (score 0):

Before using array_push to add the comp's key-value, use array_pop to get the age's value and removing it from the array.
Afterwards, we'll add the comp and the age.

($members)

```
    [0] => Array
        (
            [fname] => Calvin
            [lname] => harris
            [age] => 22
        )
```

Instead of array_push, we can simply use `$arr[$i][$key] = $val` which is faster and simple.

Code:

```
$comp = 'IT';
$age = array_pop($members[0]);
$members[0]['comp'] = $comp;
$members[0]['age'] = $age;
```

Since you didn't supplied any PHP code, I've couldn't adjust it according to your variables but I believe you got the idea.